# How to make a reliable Celery task with a blocking call inside?

Tags: python-3.x, celery

I've a Celery (4.4.7) task which makes a blocking call and may block for long time. I don't want to keep worker busy for long time, so I setup `soft_time_limit` for the task. My hope was to fail a task (if it's impossible to complete it quickly) and retry it later.

My issue is that `SoftTimeLimitExceeded` exception is not being raised (I suppose due to the call blocking on OS level). As a result the task is killed by hard `time_limit` and I don't have a chance to retry it.

```
@shared_task(
    acks_late=True,
    ignore_results=True,
    soft_time_limit=5,
    time_limit=15,
    default_retry_delay=1,
    retry_kwargs={"max_retries": 10},
    retry_backoff=True,
    retry_backoff_max=1200,  # 20 min
    retry_jitter=True,
    autoretry_for=(SoftTimeLimitExceeded,),
)
def my_task():
    blocking_call_taking_long_time()
```

What I tried:

- Hard time limit is impossible to intercept
- I expected `ack_late` would push my timed-out task back to the queue, but it doesn't happen.

  - Tried adding `reject_on_worker_lost`, neither value changes things for me
- `SoftTimeLimitExceeded` exception is 100% not there - neither `autoretry_for`, nor regular `try ... except` don't catch it

For now I ended up with setting explicit timeout for the blocking operation. This requires adding a parameter everywhere along the call chain.

Is there some other path I'm missing?

Comment: did you try those configurations in the global configuration? (not per task) I never tried per task (in the decorator) but it works for me when I define it globally

Comment: unfortunately I can't make them global at the moment since I have other tasks. though it's still worth a try to see if it makes any diff. thanks for the suggestion